# Scatterplots multiple columns in rstudio

Tags: r

i have the following data:

```
ID  VALUEA  VALUEB  TIMEA  TIMEB
0   4.3      2.1.   6.1    7.2
1   4.6      6.4.   4.1    2.2
2   4.4      3.1.   2.1    5.2
3   6.3      2.5.   4.1    7.2
4   9.3      9.1.   6.1    1.2
```

And i need to represent the data like this in Rstudio:

https://www.subeimagenes.com/img/imagen-2183442.html

The axis x is the identifier and the y is the time a and time b
I need to represent the data ordered by the time

Anyone know how to do that, i followed many tutorial but any of these helped me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for but if you want to plot 20 points with 4 distinct categories then the following will work:

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(0:4),
           VALUEA = c(4.3,4.6,4.4,6.3,9.3),
           VALUEB = c(2.1,6.4,3.1,2.5,9.1),
           TIMEA = c(6.1,4.1,2.1,4.1,6.1),
           TIMEB = c(7.2,2.2,5.2,7.2,1.2))
```

Convert to long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer` and merge the categorical variables of 'VALUE' and 'TIME' together using `tidyr::unite`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(VALUEA,VALUEB), 
               names_to = "VALUE_TYPE", 
               values_to = "VALUE", 
               names_prefix = "VALUE") %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(TIMEA,TIMEB), 
               names_to = "TIME_TYPE", 
               values_to = "TIME", 
               names_prefix = "TIME") %>% 
  unite(VALUE_TIME, c(VALUE_TYPE, TIME_TYPE), remove = FALSE) %>% 
  select(ID, VALUE_TIME,VALUE,TIME)
```

Plot using `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

df_long %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(VALUE, TIME, shape = VALUE_TIME)) +
  geom_point()
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: perfect answer!! if i need to sort the times how can i do it?

Comment: How would you like to sort the times out?